# Define custom roles for SSO logged in users

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth

I'm following the [Spring SSO with Facebook tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) and would like to define custom roles for the logged in users using an AuthentificationProvider but none of its methods are getting called during startup or runtime of the app.

Is there any simple way to extend this code to grant Facebook users custom roles?

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class FbauthTestApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FbauthTestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/webjars/**")
                    .permitAll()
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/admin.html")
                    .hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
                .and().csrf()
        .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
    }

    @Autowired
    MyAuthProvider myAuthProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(myAuthProvider);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@EnableOAuth2Sso` annotation pulls the configuration from
`ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration` class, where you can inject an `AuthoritiesExtractor`.

This is the interface which decides on what roles a specific user has. If you're not using the authorization server it is an instance of `FixedAuthoritiesExtractor`.

```
@Component
public class MyAuthoritiesExtractor implements AuthoritiesExtractor {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public List<GrantedAuthority> extractAuthorities(Map<String, Object> map) {
        String role = "ROLE_USER";
        Optional<Long> principalId = getPrincipalId(map);
        if (principalId.isPresent()) {
            User user = userRepository.findOne(principalId.get());
            role = (user != null && user.isAdmin()) ? "ROLE_ADMIN" : "ROLE_USER";
        }

        return Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
    }

    private Optional<Long> getPrincipalId(Map<String, Object> map) {
        try {
            return Optional.of(Long.parseLong(map.getOrDefault("id", "").toString()));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // log
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }
}
```

Log in, register a user as admin, log out and re-login and then you have the `ROLE_ADMIN`.